# Rails tutorial will_paginate raises undefined_method total_pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, railstutorial.org

Ive been stuck for a while now in the rails tutorial. Im in section 10.3, where we are supposed to add pagination. I have added the gem 'will-paginate' to my Gemfile, and this is the index view

```
<h1>All users</h1>
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
        <%= gravatar_for user, :size => 30 %>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

The server raises the following problem:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0xa0283fc>):
    1: <h1>All users</h1>
    2: <%= will_paginate %>
    3: <ul class="users">
    4:  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    5:      <li>
```

I have been trying to search for it.. but none of the solutions to apparently similar issues worked. Any ideas?

Comment: hi i think will_paginate takes some arguments, like <%= will_paginate @users %>, also what does the relevant controller look like?

Comment: try http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate to get a better understanding, though a bit out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just scroll lower in the tutorial - the next section addresses that problem :)

> The view in Listing 10.27 doesn’t work yet, though, because currently @users contains the results of User.all (Listing 10.20), which is of class Array, whereas will_paginate expects an object of class WillPaginate::Collection.

It then has you modify the UsersController to fix it-

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update]
  .
  .
  .
  def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: I have the problem with the code: User.scoped.order("id").paginate.. and User.order("id").paginate... Does order have to be after paginate to make paginate work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing an argument to `will_paginate`:

```
will_paginate @users
```

Comment: I tried that when i checked the will_paginate troubleshooting web, but it didnt work, it still says the same.